# How to use ASTs with Rust derive macro?

Tags: rust, macros, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create a `derive` Rust macro. I want to do all my work entirely in ASTs (without `quote!` macro, probably).

The questions:

- How to transform `TokenStream` into an AST?
- Which type the AST will be after this?
- How to transform AST back into `TokenStream`?

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(Serialize)]
pub fn serialize(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // correct?
    let ast = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

    // Which type is `ast` now?

    // correct?
    TokenStream::from(ast)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "AST" (I know it stands for "abstract syntax tree", but what AST do you want)? And what is the problem with `quote!`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I need AST, because I need to sort and reorder fields in a struct. So, I need AST of the struct from which I derive. `quote!` seems not suitable in my case, because it seems easier to reorder fields in the AST without reconstructing them with `quote!`.

Comment: [`syn::DeriveInput`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.DeriveInput.html) is already a syntax tree, arguably (although maybe not abstract, but it should not matter). You can reorder the fields there then `quote!` it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If `input` is already `DeriveInput`, what does the `parse_macro_input!` macro do?

Comment: I didn't say `input` is already `DeriveInput`, I said `DeriveInput` is already an AST.

Comment: *"I need to sort and reorder fields in a struct"* - I want to point out that a derive macro cannot modify the structure it is annotated on (it can only produce new code), just in case you were trying to do that.

Comment: @kmdreko Oh, OK, I can generate code with reordered fields, leaving the existing struct as is.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If `input` is not `DeriveInput`, then `as DeriveInput` in the code will fail... I don't understand something?

Comment: `parse_macro_input!()` takes the `TokenStream` and transforms it into `syn::DeriveInput`. If it is not valid code for that, it will fail, but we still need to construct the `DeriveInput` from the valid tokens.

Comment: The last line of the function does not work:

"the trait bound `proc_macro::TokenStream: std::convert::From<syn::DeriveInput>` is not satisfied"

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Your suggestion to `quote!` ast:
21  |     quote!(ast)
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `proc_macro::TokenStream`, found struct `quote::__private::TokenStream`

Comment: Use `quote! {}.into()`. They are different `TokenStream`.